# Windows 10 Mobile - Remember time

Tags: reminders

I often use the remember feature of the windows 10 phone, to remind me of apointments. But I always only get notified 15 minutes before the apointment, which is way too late.

How can I change this behaviour, I researched but found nothing helpful.

Comment: Is this for reminders set through Cortana, o for ones in your calendar?

Comment: The ones I set through cortana, but cortana sets them in the calendar for me, so I think this makes no difference?